# Remove unused CSS selectors with Rails/Sprockets assets pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I have run Dust-me-selectors and I found out that basically most of my deadweight comes from Bootstrap, FontAwsome and jQuery-UI. The problem is that they are installed as rubygems in order to easily update them. Is there any gem that takes a config file in YAML/JSON to configure which unused selectors(blacklist) it should remove/filter before it compresses it onto the server?
Preferably it should be done when I run "rake assets:precompile".

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution - You can Customize your Bootstrap installation, and remove parts you don't need.  See:

```
    http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
```

That will get you some of the way there, but their Customization might not be granular enough for you.